# CSS word-break: break-all doesn't break URLs?

Tags: html, css, email, word-break

I'm trying to get a long URL placed in a sidebar to break and wrap within the confines of the table cells width. I have added `style="word-break:break-all;"` to the `td` and to a `span` surrounding the text and URL but still does not wrap. It just pushes the cell below where it should be.

Is there some other way to fix this?

FYI
The code is for an HTML email and not the web which is why everything is inline.

Here it is live [link](http://skmgroupwork.com/fmcg/fmcg067a/fmcg067_COboth.html)

Comment: Try `word-wrap:break-word;`

Comment: I have added that now but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Well you should post your code and a fiddle if possible, not just a link.

Comment: I looked at your "live link" and can't tell what's wrong, because you haven't described what is out of place. By looking, I'd _guess_ it's the *Contact* block, with the _email address_ (*not* a URL) that is not breaking.

Comment: Hi Stephen P. Yes I was referring to the email address in the contact block. I guess I called it a URL since it's still an <a href=""></a>

Comment: Dan I've created a JSFiddle here if you want to review that I believe it is working now. http://jsfiddle.net/swiatekt/dhb621ok/

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with tables: they are not the most cooperative in styling with CSS.

Currently your TD must be set to display: block for the break-word solution to work. You will want to set a width as well so it doesn't effect your design too bad. You can also assign this to your span:

```
display: block;
width: 100px;
```

There are a few other alternatives as well, which I posted in the following:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jeremyhawes/q0Lkwyzs/)

Comment: Thanks jhawes. I got super excited seeing this work on my ipad and in Chrome but then of course IE was the downer IE 9 and 8 to be specific. But this def. helped me find the answer with some additional cross browser support I found on CSS-tricks here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Answer (score 0):

I have set up a JSFiddle here to display the fix in action [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swiatekt/dhb621ok/)

jhawes was correct in pointing out that my td needed a width specified. I did this as such (everything needed to be inline as this is for an email)

```
<td width="160" style="width:160px;-word-break:break-word;word-break:break:all;"></td>
```

I also needed to add display:block; as suggested (I didn't need the extra containing div element)

```
<td width="160" style="width:160px;display:block;-word-break:break-word;word-break:break:all;" </td>
```

This works great among most modern browsers but still wasn't working in IE9 and IE8. I found a cross broswer fix on CSS-tricks [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/)

So the final working td looks like this

```
<td width="160" style="width:160px;display:block;-ms-word-break: break-all;

 /* Be VERY careful with this, breaks normal words wh_erever */
 word-break: break-all;

 /* Non standard for webkit */
 word-break: break-word;

-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
 hyphens: auto;""</td>
```